# libgazebo_ros_diff_drive publishes tf based on wall clock time instead of sim time

Tags: gazebo, transforms

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using multiple turtlebot3 robots in my simulation with gazebo. The differential time plugin publishes a transform between the `odom` frame and the `base_footprint` frame. I also have a plugin which publishes the ground truth pose of the turtlebot3 `libgazebo_ros_p3d.so`.
I want to generate transformations between multiple turtlebot3 robots and to do this I have a seperate node which broadcasts transform between the `base_link` frame and the `world` frame. The problem is that the `base_link` to `world` transformations are published with the `sim_time` as I intend but for some reason the transformations between the `base_footprint` and `odom` frame are published with my computers clock time.

Because of this I cannot generate transformations between the `odom` frame and the `world` frame.

Heres what I would like my tf tree to be:

```
        -------------------- world --------------------
   tb1/base_link          tb2/base_link          tb3/base_link
        |                      |                      |
tb1/base_footprint     tb2/base_footprint     tb3/base_footprint
        |                      |                      |
    tb1/odom                tb2/odom               tb3/odom
```

Heres the snippets of code:

The main launch file:

```
<launch>
 <arg name="world_file" value="worlds/empty.world"/>
 <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
 <arg name="gui" default="false"/>
 <arg name="headless" value="true"/>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
  <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_file)"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
  <arg name="verbose" value="true"/>
</include>
```

The gazebo plugins in the turtlebot's xacro file:

```
<!-- Differential drive plugin -->
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="turtlebot3_waffle_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
    <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
    <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
    <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
    <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
    <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
    <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
    <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
    <publishTf>true</publishTf>
    <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
    <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
    <updateRate>30</updateRate>
    <leftJoint>wheel_left_joint</leftJoint>
    <rightJoint>wheel_right_joint</rightJoint>
    <wheelSeparation>0.287</wheelSeparation>
    <wheelDiameter>0.066</wheelDiameter>
    <wheelAcceleration>1</wheelAcceleration>
    <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
    <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
<!-- ground truth publisher-->
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>ground_truth_pose</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
    <frameName>world</frameName>
    <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
    <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Turtlebot3.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model"/>
  <arg name="namespace" value="$(arg model)_$(arg robotID)" />

  <group ns="/$(arg namespace)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

<!-- Gazebo model spawner -->
    <node name="spawn_burger" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
            args="-param robot_description
                  -urdf
                  -x $(arg x)
                  -y $(arg y)
                  -z 0.02
                  -model $(arg namespace)"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

`base_link` to `world` tf broadcaster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import sys
import tf
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

def update_tf(data):
  transform_from = "{}/base_link".format(ns)
  transform_to   = "world"
  pos = data.pose.pose.position
  ori = data.pose.pose.orientation
  orientation = [ori.x, ori.y, ori.z, ori.w]
  position    = [pos.x, pos.y, pos.z]
  br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
  print rospy.Time.now()
  br.sendTransform(position, orientation, rospy.Time.now(), transform_from, transform_to)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ns = sys.argv[1]
  rospy.init_node("tf_broadcaster_{}".format(ns.split('_')[1]))
  pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("{}/ground_truth_pose".format(ns), Odometry, update_tf)
  rospy.spin()
```

Here's the output from the `/tf` topic:

```
 transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
       secs: 2764768896
       nsecs:     32752
       frame_id: "burger_2/odom"
    child_frame_id: "burger_2/base_footprint"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 2.20744910982
        y: 2.01895292219
        z: -0.000612418868214
      rotation: 
        x: -0.000874178201541
        y: -0.000801260462534
        z: 0.999653654558
        w: -0.0262900118476
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 102756
        nsecs: 880000000
      frame_id: "world"
    child_frame_id: "burger_1/base_footprint"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 1.32845899318
        y: 0.92220015314
        z: -0.0104010663862
      rotation: 
        x: 0.000706580835481
        y: 0.000460995693433
        z: 0.0407422461322
        w: -0.9991693338
---
```

`rosrun tf view_frams` gives the fowwing output:

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame burger_2/base_footprint at time 2.76477e+09 according to authority /gazebo
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.18/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame burger_2/base_footprint at time 2.76477e+09 according to authority /gazebo
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 277 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-tf2-0.5.18/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

`roswtf` ouput:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /gazebo:
   * /gazebo/set_model_state
   * /gazebo/set_link_state

WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/tf_broadcaster_1] that differed from ROS time by -1.38s
 * receiving transform from [/gazebo] that differed from ROS time by 4001227263.39s
```

I even tried passing `<param name="use_sim_time" value="true">` in the turtlebot's launch file but in vain ...
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20646/libgazebo_ros_diff_drive-publishes-tf-based-on-wall-clock-time-instead-of-sim-time/) by [AAbattery](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6896/aabattery/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-10**:
There's been a recent ABI breakage on ROS time, could you try upgrading to the latest Kinetic debs and try again?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-10**:
There's been a recent ABI breakage on ROS time which has been fixed, could you try upgrading to the latest Kinetic debs and try again?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2018-10-10**:
what version of gazebo and ROS are you using? Did the problem only started happening recently?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2018-10-15**:
Related issue: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2536/update-gazebo8_ros_pkgs-to-fix-abi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This should be fixed in the new release of gazebo8-ros-pkgs (2.5.17). Doing a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` will make sure you get the latest debs. Alternatively, you can add gazebo_ros_pkgs to your workspace and build from source to bypass the ABI compatibility issue.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2018-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1